# KeyError:0 in in len function

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I have tried to apply Xgboost regression in pennylane quantum machine learning with the Boston House Dataset. My question is not related to the quantum part, the question is related to KeyError:0.
Please have look at the code and help me.

**Code**

```
#Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import xgboost
import shap
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.nn.functional import relu
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston_dataset = load_boston()
boston = pd.DataFrame(boston_dataset.data, columns=boston_dataset.feature_names)
boston['MEDV'] = boston_dataset.target
boston.head()
```

[image]

```
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane.templates import AngleEmbedding, StronglyEntanglingLayers
from pennylane.operation import Tensor

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)
import xgboost
import shap

# train an XGBoost model
X, y = shap.datasets.boston()
model = xgboost.XGBRegressor().fit(X, y)

# explain the model's predictions using SHAP
# (same syntax works for LightGBM, CatBoost, scikit-learn, transformers, Spark, etc.)
explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X)

# visualize the first prediction's explanation
shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values[0])
```

[image]

```
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

X= boston.iloc[:,[4,10,11,12]]
y = boston.iloc[:,13]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

print(len(X_train))
print(len(y_train))
print(len(X))
print(len(y))
X_train.shape
#404,404,506,506,(404,4)

n_qubits = len(X_train[0])
n_qubits
```

[image]

Comment: `X_train` is a dataframe so when you do `[0]` on it it looks for a column named literally `0` and fails as it doesn't exist. Assuming you want to look at the first *row* of `X_train`, try `X_train.iloc[0]`.

Comment: @MustafaAydın, I have tried your suggestion, and the code is working now. Many thanks for your help.